Geometric distribution case

Assume that the number of errors along a magnetic
recording surface is a Poisson random variable with a mean
of one error every $10^5$ bits. A sector of data consists of $4096$
eight-bit bytes.

What is the mean number of sectors until an error occurs?


Taken from $\textit{'Applied Statistics and Probability for Engineers'}$
;$\;$ $ 6th$
edition;$\;$ $2014$
;p.$105$
Firstly, as $\frac{4096 \times 8}{10^5} = 0.32768$, the random variable $X$ of the number of error per sector follows the distribution $\mathit{P}(0.32768)$ and that leads to:
$$P(X \geq 1)=1-F(0)=1-\exp(-0.32768) \approx 0.2794$$
Now defining the geometric variable $Y \sim BN(1,0.2794064)$, we have that:
$$E(Y)=\frac{1}{0.2794}\approx3.58$$
Are all the steps taken above correct?

Your method and exponential approximation is reasonable, while $\dfrac{1}{1-(1-10^{-5})^{4096 \times 8}}\approx 3.5790006$ is a little more precise,  if you want the expected number of sectors up to and including the first sector to have errors. Clearly this would become an expected $2.5790006$ sectors strictly before the first with errors, so the desired answer may depend on what until means.
